# How can i write a query that counts the number of rows of an id within a condition from two tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to write a query that returns the names of the artitsts and their number of tracks in the archive, but only if a =< # of tracks =< b, given a and b.

My problem is that I don't know how to include the condition.
I tried this query but obviusly it doesn't include the lower and upper bounds.

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM artists, albums
ON artists.ArtistId = albums.ArtistId
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY cnt DESC, Name ASC
```

These are the tables

```
CREATE TABLE "albums"
(
    [AlbumId] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    [Title] NVARCHAR(160)  NOT NULL,
    [ArtistId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ([ArtistId]) REFERENCES "artists" ([ArtistId]) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE "artists"
(
    [ArtistId] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(120)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your query. you can use `HAVING` and `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(1) as cnt
FROM artists
JOIN albums on artists.ArtistId = albums.ArtistId
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(1) BETWEEN 1 and 5
ORDER BY cnt DESC, Name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [`HAVING`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) syntax. It will allow you to add conditions after the group by has been completed:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM artists, albums
ON artists.ArtistId = albums.ArtistId
GROUP BY Name
HAVING cnt >= 5 AND cnt <= 10
ORDER BY cnt DESC, Name ASC
```